# Using ng-repeat object value as javascript parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a code that looks something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="obj in objs">
  <td onClick = "someFunction({{obj.val1}})">{{obj.val2}}</td>
  <td>{{obj.val3}}</td>
</tr>
```

The colums properly show val2 and val3, but the onclick method I'm trying to define doesn't work as the code doesn't translate from `{{obj.val1}}` into the proper value, it stays as is.

How do I properly send `{{obj.val1}}` onto the onClick event? Can this be done?

Comment: try ng-click="someFunction(obj.val1)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ng-click` instead of `onClick` and assign the `someFunction()` function to angular `$scope`

Comment: While everyone is technically correct, only you mentioned that I had to also put the function inside $scope to be able to use it with ng-click, so I'm choosing your answer

Comment: Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

In angular they already have directive called `ng-click` **The ngClick directive allows you to specify custom behavior when an element is clicked.** which used for click event. And You don't need to bind the parameter `{{}}`

then your code come like

```
<tr ng-repeat="obj in objs">
  <td ng-click = "someFunction(obj.val1)">{{obj.val2}}</td>
  <td>{{obj.val3}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done.Using ng-click

```
    <tr ng-repeat="obj in objs">
    <td ng-click = "someFunction(obj.val1)">{{obj.val2}}</td>
    <td>{{obj.val3}}</td>
    </tr>
```

You don't need to bind the values using {{}}, you can simply put them as function parameters.

Answer (score -2):

Do this :

```
<td onClick = "someFunction(obj.val1)">{{obj.val2}}</td>
```